Duo redirect URI is invalid
I used duo_universal_php to add the push notification to my mobile to authorize the user's login. Once the user try to login to my Laravel platform I needed to add the Duo push notification to verify the login.
I created a Service for this:
class DuoAuthenticationService
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client(
            config('duo.client_id'),
            config('duo.client_secret'),
            config('duo.api_hostname'),
            config('duo.redirect_uri')
        );
    }

    public function initiateAuthentication($username)
    {
        $state = $this->client->generateState();
        $authUrl = $this->client->createAuthUrl($username, $state);

        return $authUrl;
    }
}

I got these client_id & secret_id by creating an application in Duo admin panel as Web SDK.
Once I called this initiateAuthentication() function, it returns following error:
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid redirect URI 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/duo/callback'."
}

For the redirect URI I added it from .env as DUO_REDIRECT_URI="http://127.0.0.1:8000/duo/callback".
I really appreciate anyone could help me with this please. My project is on Laravel 6.0 & php version is 7.2

https://duo.com/docs/duoweb#first-steps says, below the heading "What should I use as the redirect URI?": "Must be a well-formed with a valid HTTPS URL and port, using a hostname (not an IP address), and a maximum length of 1024 characters."
